# I need help with installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside to Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I bought a new Lenovo B350 with Windows 8 pre-installed.  Should I continue with the windows setup and then just download 14.04 from the Ubuntu website?  I tried just booting a 14.04 DVD and it did not install.  The computer remained on the acceptance of Windows window.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean it ignored the dvd and booted into windows instead? If that is what happened you need to change the boot order in your bios to boot from cd before the hard drive

Comment: It sounded like it was reading the DVD and then stopped and did nothing.  It remained on the window that asked me if I accepted Windows 8 policies.  Does that help?  I am not that computer literate to change bios and such.

Answer (score 0):

Editing and viewing the bios is easy. When your computer boots the first screen you see will have the option to go to bios menu. It's one of the f-keys. You may have to restart a couple times cause the screen doesnt stay very long. In the menu you should see the boot order and be able to change it if it isnt already set to boot from cd/dvd drive first. 
This wont stop it from booting normally if you dont have a cd in the drive.
When it boots from the cd you will be given the option to run it live or install. I would recommend trying it live first

Comment: If you burned the dvd yourself, and didnt burn it as an iso image, you will not be able to boot from that dvd.

Answer (score 0):

Most unfortunately I believe you will need to finish the installation of Windows first - the pre-installed system has not done it's final configurations yet, and it will be difficult to utilize the computer until this is complete.

The exception to this would be if you decide to dump Windows entirely - if you have Ubuntu downloaded from another computer, you could boot to the CD / USB and format the HDD, which would bypass the Windows configuration.